# vim ConqueTerm running bpython LookupError

Tags: bash, vim, bpython

I am trying to run bpython in my VIM ConqueTerm, but I got the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):stebin  <F9> Pager  <F2> Show Source
  File "/usr/local/bin/bpython", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('bpython==0.10.1', 'console_scripts', 'bpython')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bpython/cli.py", line 1756, in main
    banner=banner)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bpython/cli.py", line 1658, in curses_wrapper
    return func(stdscr, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bpython/cli.py", line 1708, in main_curses
    clirepl = CLIRepl(main_win, interpreter, statusbar, config, idle)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bpython/cli.py", line 261, in __init__
    repl.Repl.__init__(self, interp, config)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bpython/repl.py", line 355, in __init__
    self.rl_history.load(pythonhist, getpreferredencoding())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/bpython/repl.py", line 208, in load
    with codecs.open(filename, 'r', encoding, 'ignore') as hfile:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/codecs.py", line 884, in open
    info = lookup(encoding)
LookupError: unknown encoding:
```

I am using MacVim and Bash.

Comment: Does it work in the terminal outside of vim?

Comment: @Conner yes, it does, but when I am in conqueterm, it's not working..

Comment: Do you have the latest version of conque?

Comment: Also, see this: http://code.google.com/p/conque/issues/detail?id=27

Comment: @Conner I just realized, if I launch mvim from terminal, bpython works in conqueterm but without any color, but if I launch it from Dock, the above error appears.

Comment: I am also using latest Conque-shell 2.3